# can't define a function which returns std::vector<string> written in jupyter notebook (ROOT kernel)

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook

I'm using ROOT in jupyter notebook and have a problem when defining the following function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//---cell separation---
using namespace std;
//---cell separation---
vector<string> split(string input, char delim){
     vector<string> ret;
     string temp;
     for(char letter:input){
         if(letter!=delim){
             temp+= letter;
         }else{
             ret.push_back(temp);
             temp.clear();
         }
     }
     ret.push_back(temp);
     return ret;
}
```

The jupyter cell returns an error message as follows:

> error: function definition is not allowed here

> vector< string> split(string input, char delim){
> ^

and the split function isn't defined.
I however write the same code and can compile it by local g++, and it works normally.

Is it a known ROOT bug? I think the function definition may be interpreted as some instanciation of a vector object.

I'm looking for alternative ways to avoid this problem.

Comment: I know it works as I tried https://ideone.com/7GQGFk

Comment: Guys, trying to reproduce in a C++ compiler is missing the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This board (https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling/issues/40) gives me an alternative way such as using auto or typedef to replace "vector< string>" and it works.

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. I am using cling 0.5, jupyter 4.4.0 in MacOS Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0